# How to link style.css in functions.php

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm a newbie to WordPress; I just started learning WordPress. I'm trying to link style.css in functions.php but I am unable to achieve what might be the issue here. Can anyone point me the right direction?

index.php

```
<?php
get_header();
?>


<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) {

        while ( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            echo 'Posts are foound';
       }
    } else {
    echo 'No Posts are found';
    }
?>
<div class="inner">
    <?php bloginfo('title'); ?><br>
    <?php bloginfo('description'); ?>
    <?php echo "<h1>Hello world</h1>"; ?>
</div>

<?php
    get_footer();
```

functions.php

```
   function mortal_theme() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
  }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mortal_theme' );
```

style.css

```
 h1 {
   background-color: red;
   color: yellow;
   font-size: 28px;
   font-weight: 700;
 }
.inner {
   width: 1100px;
   margin: 0 auto;

}
```

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
   <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
   <header class="site-header">
      <?php bloginfo('title'); ?>
   </header>
```

footer.php

```
     <footer>
        <p><?php bloginfo('title');?> - &copy; <?php echo date('Y');?></p>
     </footer>
  <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Your index.php appears to be missing `get_header()`. Your theme needs to have a header.php with the `<head>` element in it, and the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` function inside it.

Comment: Jacob - they had the `get_header()` call in there, it just didn't show up because the code wasn't formatted properly.  I edited for code formatting (that doesn't answer whether there's a header.php or not, though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this working:

**(1) Your `index.php` file should begin with:**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

and end with:

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**(2) Your `header.php` file should have the following right *before* the closing `</head>` tag:**

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Note: `header.php` also has other things, but I am assuming you have them set up already.

**(3) Your `footer.php` file should have the following right *before* the closing `</body>` tag:**

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

**(4) In your `functions.php`, modify your the second line of your wp_enqueue_style so that it looks like this:**

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

The whole function in the end should look like this:

```
function mortal_theme() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() );
  }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mortal_theme' );
```

This is because the `style.css` in your theme folder is the *main* stylesheet for the theme - so you don't need to tell WordPress to look for `style.css`, it will know what to look for.

**Update:**

I have recreated your theme using your code on a local WordPress installation to test it, and here is a screenshot of what I see when I visit the page:

[image]

The theme folder has the following files:

1. `style.css`
2. `index.php`
3. `header.php`
4. `functions.php`
5. `footer.php`

And I copied and pasted the **exact** code for each file from your original question, with *one* exception: for `functions.php` I added the starting `<?php` tag so my final code looks like this:

```
<?php
   function mortal_theme() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css);
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mortal_theme' );
```

Based on the screenshot above, everything seems to be working correctly.

However, if I remove the `<?php` that I added (to make my code match the one in your question 100%), this is what I see when I view the page:

[image]

**What do you see when you view your page?** If you're getting results like that in the second screenshot, then it is because you do not have the starting `<?php` in the beginning of your `functions.php` file. Add that and you're good to go, insha'Allah.

Comment: I have written same as you said but not working. Can you help me out

Comment: Sure. But first, can you update your original question to include the full contents of your `header.php` and `footer.php` so I can get a better look at what you have and what might be missing?

Comment: I updated my question check now.

Comment: Ok, your `header.php` is missing the opening `<body>` tag. Be sure to add it right after the closing `</head>` tag. Then, in your `index.php` file, please check that the last php tag is closed so that it looks like this: `<?php wp_footer(); ?> `, because right now it is showing the semicolon as the last part.

Comment: i made the changes.

Comment: And is it working now?

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Does your `functions.php` file begin with `<?php` (in the first line)?

Comment: yes <?php //code here ?>

Comment: Remove the closing `?>` from `functions.php`, it can sometimes break the site.

Comment: yeah i have remove but still not working what might be the issue :(

Comment: In your WordPress admin area under Appearances/Themes, are there any message about your mortal theme?

Comment: There is no message.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website so I can take a further look into this?

Comment: I'm working on the local server.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comments. Please check it and let me know if it helps and/or if you need further assistance or clarification.

Comment: This one is better the documentation. It works with the latest version nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Please check [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).
First of all create a function with any name you like ei: my_function and include your css file and then hook this function with `wp_enqueue_scripts`. Here is what I mean:

```
function my_function() {
    // This will load your default style.css
    wp_enqueue_style('main_style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function');
```

But if you want to load another CSS file which isn't your WP style.css then you have to mention proper path. EI:

```
function my_function() {
    // This will load your default style.css
    wp_enqueue_style('main_style', get_stylesheet_uri());

    // This will load custom.css located in the css folder
    wp_enqueue_style('main_style', get_theme_file_uri('css/custom.css'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function');
```

Comment: As above I wrote the same as you mention.

Comment: Is it working now? If you are using child theme `get_template_directory_uri` will not work for you because it returns root url of main theme.

Comment: Please also make sure that you are including `header.php` to every single template files including `index.php`, `page.php`, `single.php`, etc. Otherwise the stylesheets will not be included because we are including those stylesheets in `header` using above function. Here is what I mean: `<?php get_header(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If it is child theme load stylesheet from child theme's directory as follows:

```
wp_enqueue_style('child-theme-styling', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css');
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are copy and pasting the exact function over there.

```
function mortal_theme() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css);
}    
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mortal_theme');
```

This code will work only if you add the end tag at the end of the code. It should look like this exactly.

Try putting an end tag at you end of the code '?>'
Hopefully this will work for you.